# Capture stdout of django runserver with Popen

Tags: python, django, popen

I'm trying to run 'runserver' (and testserver) in a separate process, and read the output in the main while the server is still running (I would like to do some automatic e2e tests).
I can't manage to store write stdout to a file. I'm using python 3.4 and django 1.7

```
from subprocess import Popen
from time import sleep
out = open('/tmp/o', 'w')
p = Popen(['./manage.py', 'runserver'] , stdout = out)
sleep(5)
out.flush()
p.terminate()
p.wait()
out.close()
print(open('/tmp/o').read())
#  stdout file is empty

# Making sure the same command with stdout=None prints something
Popen(['./manage.py', 'runserver'] )
# prints output as expected
sleep(5)
p.terminate()
p.wait()
```

I'm obviously doing something wrong, but I couldn't find any help in the docs or in any other stackoverflow question.

Thanks

Mirko

Answer (score 3):

I found my answer here:
https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/19593#comment:4

Setting the environment variable PYTHONUNBUFFERED fixes the issue

```
env = dict(os.environ, **{'PYTHONUNBUFFERED':'1'})

out = open('/tmp/o', 'w')
p = Popen(['./manage.py', 'runserver', '-v', '3'] , stdout = out, env = env)
```